# reading csv file into python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api

I want to read a csv file into a pandas dataframe, but I get the following error

[image: error]

when executing this code:

```py
filepath = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bUTjF-iM4WW7g_Iii62Zx56XNTkF2-I1/view"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
df.head(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve information or data from google drive, at first, you need to identify the file id.

```
import pandas as pd

url='https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GhBwm5vaB2ekdlZW5WZnppb28/view?usp=sharing'
file_id=url.split('/')[-2]
dwn_url='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + file_id
df = pd.read_csv(dwn_url)
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet to read the CSV from Google Drive into the pandas DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1bUTjF-iM4WW7g_Iii62Zx56XNTkF2-I1"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.head(5)
```